# How can I make an implementation of pure virtual function in derived class be another pure virtual function?

Tags: c++

Consider

```
class A
{
protected:
 virtual void function() =0;
}

class B: public class A 
{
protected:
 virtual void function() { blah blah blah };
}
```

I want to make function() in class B also a pure virtual function. That is, derived classes of B must make another implementation of function(). How can I perform this task?

Comment: What is stopping you?  What have you tried?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any derived class that doesn't implement all the base class's pure virtual methods is an abstract class so you cannot instantiate it. So you have to implement the latter.

- Also remove the keyword `class` when declaring inherited class:

  ```
  class B: public class A
  ```

To be:

```
class B: public A {

};
```

Also the semicolon is not redundant so add it to each end of class declaration.

```
    class A{
        public:
            virtual void function() =0;
    };

    class B: public A {
        public:
            virtual void function()= 0; // B is an ADT due to this pure method function.
    };

    void B::function() {
            std::cout << "B::function()" << std::endl;
    };

    class C : public B{
        public:
            void function(){
                    B::function();
                    std::cout << "C::funtion()" << std::endl;
            }
    };

    int main(){

    //  A aObj; // error
    //  B bObj; // error
        C cObj; // correct
        cObj.function();

        return 0;
    }
```

- As you can see in class B I make the method `function` pure so it cannot be instantiate it. I Also add a definition to it so that object of derived classes can `chain up` for functionality.

You can also make be ADT:

```
class B : public A{
    // it is sufficient to make it ADT by not implementing the base pure method function.
};
```

Comment: You can't define a pure virtual function immediately...

Comment: @Rakete1111: What is your proof? - What about `chaining up`?

Comment: The language just disallows it ([ref](http://eel.is/c++draft/class#mem-11.sentence-3)). This has nothing to do with "chaining up", `virtual void f() = 0 {}` is not valid C++.

Comment: The code runs correctly on msvc++ 14?

Comment: Yeah, MSVC is not very standards compliant, although it has improved in VS2017.

Comment: @Rakete1111: Thanks a lot! I'll edit the code.